# Accept requests from Lan when Internet is down

Tags: routing, lan

I have a server with a Real IP serving a web application.

Sometimes the internet goes down and I need the local client machines to be still able to access that server from LAN.

What is the easiest solution for this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "_Real IP_?" There are two IPs (IPv4 and IPv6), and they are both real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the easiest solution for this situation?

The keyword is split-brain DNS.

Instead of using the same DNS resolution as external clients to the (router's) *public* IP address and requiring cumbersome NAT hairpinning, you set up your local DNS to resolve the server name to its *private* IP address, so clients have no need to use the WAN router.

Note that applications like DNS and protocols above the transport layer are explicitly off-topic here.